# ToDo-App Checkmark

Tags: ios, checkbox, checkmark

Each todo app has a empty box on the left handside, when you touch the box, it changes to a checked box. When you tap it again, the checkmark disappears. I think everybody knows what I mean.

As you see it here (right):

[image: Screenshot]

How would I realize something like that ? Is it a UIButton ?
I'm working with Core Data, how would I save the state ? With a boolean varibale ?

I tried to solve my problem now for days, but wasn't able to get it work.

Would be soo nice, when you could help me. 
Thx a lot !
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `UIButton` with different images for the default and selected states. Then, if you set the `selected` property to `YES`, the selected image will show instead.

To store it, I'd say that a `BOOL` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. How does it work with the cellForRowAtIndexPath ? And how do I work with the Button for the row it is in. A bit of Code would be very helpful.
I now made it this way: if (self.selectedButton.selected == YES) {
  [selectedButton setSelected:NO];
 }
 else {
 [selectedButton setSelected:YES];
 }
But how do I connect that to the row in the tableview ? I hope you can understand what I mean :| thx a lot !!

Comment: You should either use a cell subclass, where you can add the `UIButton`, or add a tag to the `UIButton`, so you can search for it in the view hierarchy.
Small inline tip: you may want to do `self.selectedButton.selected = !self.selectedButton.selected`